# Binding Dropdown list on Razor Page to Database Table

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, entity-framework-core, dropdown, razor-pages

I am an absolute beginner with razor pages, asp.net and visual studio. I followed a wonderful tutorial on asp.net and razor pages to get me started on YouTube.

However, now I am stuck. What I am trying to do:

I have a page Create.cshtml that users input data into and it posts to a database table (InfoSite). This works well, but I wanted to create a drop-down list for one of the fields. I can create a static list the drop-down, but I would like to create a drop-down list that is based on the values in another database table (ResCategory), so that users can update those ResCategory values if needed and they will then automatically appear in the drop-down.

I now have part of it working. The drop-down list on the Create.cshtml page will read the values in the ResCategory table, but when I click the Submit button to add that record, it will not post/bind the drop-down box selection to the InfoSite table. It posts/binds everything else from that page though.

Likely, I am missing something simple, but just cannot figure out what. One of my biggest issues right now is not knowing "where" certain code needs to go yet!

Here is what I have so far:

On the Create.cshtml page, I have this code:

```
<select id="ResType" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.displayResCatdata,"ID","Description"))" class="form-select">  
                        <option value="" selected disabled>---Select Residence Type---</option>
</select>
```

On the Create.cshtml.cs, I have this:

```cs
public IEnumerable<ResCategory> displayResCatdata { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        displayResCatdata = await _db.ResCategory.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        await _db.InfoSite.AddAsync(InfoSite);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        TempData["success"] = "Site Information added successfully.";
        return RedirectToPage("Index");
    }
```

And, then on my InfoSite.cs, I have:

```cs
    public class InfoSite
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Office Type")]
        public string? Specialty { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Res Type")]
        public string? ResType { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Res Sub Type")]
        public string? ResSubType { get; set; }.....
```

I'm sure that I shouldn't be putting "public string? for the Res Type { get; set; }, but I am not sure what to use. Also, I think something must be off somewhere else.

Could someone please give specific instruction as to what I may be missing and EXACTLY where I might be missing it?

Comment: I'm not a razor pages guru, but one thing I noticed is that your `select` element does not have a name attribute.  The name attribute should match the name of the property on your model.  You can inspect the POST of your form submission using F12 Developer Tools, Network Tab, or drop a breakpoint on your server side method that receives the POST, and inspect how the model is populating there.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not understanding what you mean. Could you please tell me where you are referring to when you refer to the select element not having a name attribute - and what you mean by the "property on your model"? As I said, I am super, super new to this. Perhaps give a "corrected" example? Thank you!

Comment: Your `<select>` tag does not have a `name` attribute.  POST requires a name attribute in order to associate the tag with your model.  So, for example: `<select name="SomeModelPropertyName" id="ResType">`

Comment: I was confusing Id with name. Sorry. I added a name ="ResType" to my <select ...> on my Create.cshtml page and it still does not populate the selected value in the table when I submit the data.

Should the name match the name of the field on the InfoSite.cs file? ie, the field that I want to fill with that value is:

public string? ResType { get; set; }

Referring back to the your first reply, I would assume the above is what you mean. So, I now have <select name="ResType" ... to match the above and it still does not work.

Comment: If the name of the Model property is ResType, then yes, the name attribute on the select tag should be ResType.  Have you inspected what exactly is being POSTed by using the Network tab in F12 developer tools?  You should be able to see exactly what is posting.  Is ResType being posted at all?  If it's not posting at all, make sure the select tag is inside your form tag.

Comment: I'm not familiar with where to access F12 developer tools. I am looking at the database table though in SQL Server Management Studio and the value that is displayed on that row of data for that field is NULL.

Comment: Yes, it is inside my form tag. As I said, everything else for that form is posting correctly, just not the ResType field value.

Comment: F12 developer tools is a tool you can use when running your web app.  Before you submit your form, press F12 (it may be a different function key depending on your browser but most use F12), and go to the Network tab.  Submit while viewing the network tab and you will see the posted payload.  You can inspect it and see exactly what is posted.  Another option is to drop a breakpoint in your method that receives the posted form, and inspect what gets posted there.  Looking at your database doesn't tell you at what point the problem is occurring. Maybe google some debug techniques to help?

Comment: Thanks very much for that. I did as you suggested and it is grabbing a number value that is the ID for the Res Category types in the ResCategory.cs model. That much is correct. It just isn't recording that in the InfoSites table.

Comment: Believe me, I spent hours upon hours "googling" before asking this question.

Comment: Well, you now know that the issue is with how your model is saving the data, which means the problem is not with the `select` tag or view.  I'd recommend that you drop a break point in that method which is responsible for receiving the form data, and step through to verify how / what is being done.

Comment: I can put a breakpoint in. The issue is that I don't know what I am looking at/for yet. As I said, I am an ABSOLUTE BEGINNER. That is why I posted the question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much trial and error and reading, reading, reading, I have answered my own question.

What was missing was actually on one tiny thing on my Create.cshtml page.

I was missing the 'asp-for' in order to bind the selected choice. So, instead of:

```
<select id="ResType" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.displayResCatdata,"ID","Description"))" class="form-select">  
                        <option value="" selected disabled>---Select Residence Type---</option>
</select>
```

I should have had:

```
<select asp-for="InfoSite.ResType" id="Select1" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayResCatData,"ID", "Description"))"><option value="" selected disabled>---Select Residence Type---</option></select>
```

My only remaining question is that even though the ID is being bound, I would prefer to be able to bind the description as that is what I would really like in the InfoSite table, but at least it is binding. That will be a question for another thread!

Comment: Also figured out how to bind the description. That was a simple change as well. Instead of: @(new SelectList(Model.DisplayResCatData,"ID", "Description")), I should have had: @(new SelectList(Model.DisplayResCatData,"Description", "Description")). The 2nd parameter needed to be changed to 'Description'. That's all there was to it!

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the data to your method in the controller.

The solution:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(InfoSite InfoSite)
{
    await _db.InfoSite.AddAsync(InfoSite);
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    TempData["success"] = "Site Information added successfully.";
    return RedirectToPage("Index");
}
```

Or

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    var infoSite = new InfoSite();
    return this.View(infoSite);
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(InfoSite InfoSite)
{
    await _db.InfoSite.AddAsync(InfoSite);
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    TempData["success"] = "Site Information added successfully.";
    return RedirectToPage("Index");
}
```

Comment: Adding 'InfoSite InfoSite' to the     "public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()" did not work. When I submitted a test entry, everything posted to the InfoSite table EXCEPT the value selected in the ResCategory dropdown. Again, everything ELSE is posting fine, just not the value from the dropdown.

Comment: Also tried the "Or" suggestion, but the 'View' created an error I did not know how to resolve.

'CreateModel' does not contain a definition for 'View' and no accessible extension method 'View' accepting a first argument of type PHECWeb 'CreateModel' could be found (are you missing a suing directive or an assembly reference?)